fix project root for elpy
I have following in the settings file:
(setq elpy-project-root "~/Development")

But it doesn't work. I have to explicitly from within emacs have to call elpy-set-project-root which works. But it resets to the directory of the file i have choosen. How can I fix the project-root in elpy.
For me, dumbjump is not working as well. So need some solution. Thanks.

Do C-h v elpy-project-root and check the value.  Then call elpy-set-project-root as you are and redo C-h v elpy-project-root. Do you see different paths?
It is possible that "~/Development" is not expanding to "/path/to/home/username/Development" or whatever.

That helped. I can see that the project root resets to nil after directory change. The helpdoc says "Setting this variable globally will override Elpy’s automatic
project detection facilities entirely." I did put this in one of the init files (setq elpy-project-root "/home/.../Development/") but this didn't work.

I put the (setq ...) command before the (use-package elpy
:straight t
:bind...) and that seems to work.
